# Change language of the date stored in d-M-Y format php

Tags: php, datetime, unix, time, epoch

I need to convert or change the language of the data I echo in php

```
echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date));
```

This echo for example 23-Jan-2017, while I want it in Spanish 23-Ene-2017.

Comment: If you decided to down-vote please tell us in comment why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I use this in wordpress so I used `date_i18n()`

```
echo date_i18n('d-M-Y', strtotime( $date ));
```

Comment: that's a wordpress function, it's not in native php... It also [does things](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4cf5550d8d7f227d760f779f250a8fb2cfa2c8c9/wp-includes/functions.php#L89) in best traditions of wordpress: instead of 2 elegant lines it just creeps the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the `setlocale()` and `strftime()` functions instead of `date()`.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
echo strftime("%d-%h-%Y", strtotime($date));
```

This will give you the desired result:

```
23-Ene-2017
```

Please note, that in order to display spanish localization, you must have spanish localization installed.